# Are there any movies where veg*ism plays a major role in the plot?

Tags: veganism

I wonder if there are any movies where the story has something to do with vegetarianism/veganism.

I'll give an example: let's think about the famous movie *One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest*. It's a movie, not a documentary, but it gives a cutting perspective on the situation inside psychiatric hospitals.

Or if we think about *Boys Don't Cry*, it's about the violence against LGBT people, but still it's not a documentary.

So are there any movies where veg*ism plays a major role in the plot?

Comment: I suppose you are not interested in veg*n documentaries, are you? Also, are you also interested in TV shows or only in movies?

Comment: The question is not about documentaries (I already know many). TV shows.. maybe yes.

Comment: _Soylent Green_ is /sort of/ about pescatarianism... until the plot twist... ;)

Comment: Why do you think it so important to show that these examples are not “documentary”?  Relevance with real-world concerns is often done in fictional stories … I hope that didn't come off as patronizing.

Answer (score 9):

Carnage by Simon Amstell recently came out. It's a comedy mockumentary set in 2067 that looks back on how veganism slowly became more popular until eventually killing animals for food became illegal. The official description is:

> It's 2067, the UK is vegan, but older generations are suffering the guilt of their carnivorous past. Simon Amstell asks us to forgive them for the horrors of what they swallowed.

- [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt6667360/)
- [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSreSNaLtZQ)
- [Film on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=930Xef1ri4M)

Answer (score 2):

Elijah Wood as Jonathan Safran Foer in "Everything Is Illuminated" and Suraj Sharma as Pi Patel in "Life of Pi" come to mind.
I have found below list on prime.peta. Life of Pi is not listed on there though... Veg-ism plays a bigger part in some films than in others on this list, I know most of the films from there and have only included the ones where I think veg-ism plays a bigger role:

- [Vegetarian and Vegan Characters in Films: Who Is Your Favorite?](http://prime.peta.org/2010/09/vegetarian-and-vegan-characters-in-films-who-is-your-favorite)

  1. In Year of the Dog, the characters played by Peter Sarsgaard and Molly Shannon are both strong supporters of animal rights.
  2. Legally Blond and Legally Blond 2 feature Reese Witherspoon as Elle Woods, a vegetarian determined to fight vivisection.
  3. Elijah Wood plays Jonathan Safran Foer in Everything Is Illuminated, which includes a memorably funny scene about vegetarianism:
  4. In Seven Pounds, Woody Harrelson’s character is vegan, and Rosario Dawson plays a vegetarian who has a vegetarian dog.
  5. In Twilight, Kristen Stewart plays Bella Swan, a vegetarian who really enjoys her veggie burgers. And don’t forget those vegetarian vampires!
  6. Colin Beaven’s role in No Impact Man: The Documentary isn’t fictional like the others listed, but I am including it anyway—I was very glad to see that Colin and his wife decided to add vegetarianism to their list of environmentally friendly things to do.
  7. Pieces of April features Katie Holmes as April Burns, the quintessential vegetarian trying to please her meat-eating family by cooking a turkey for their Thanksgiving dinner.
  8. Albert Brooks plays vegetarian character John Henderson in the 1996 movie Mother. Some of the dialogue between Brooks’ character and his mother in the film reminded me of conversations that I’ve had with my own mother (she just didn’t get it!).